Is it legal to take a copyrighted test, modify it, then distribute it for free?
There is a psychological test called the YSQ. It is copyrighted, and one needs a license to use it.
In 2021, a revised version called YSQ-R was created by a different person. In the YSQ-R, some questions are removed, and the grouping of the questions is changed a little. The YSQ-R is distributed for free.
Is this legal? If not, are the users taking it committing a crime? The only excuse I can think of is that the questions themselves are not very valuable/original, and the actual work is conducting an experiment to validate the test.

on a non-copyright level: sharing psychological tests can result in invalidation of the whole test, if the method of answer-scoring becomes known with it. If you know the questions and have time to research it first, and craft your answers, you can fool the tester.
